# Can liquid hydrogen be ionized?

Tags: hydrogen, liquid-state

Does stripping the electrons off of hydrogen atoms affect it's boiling point in any way?

Comment: Are you talking about full or only partial ionization?

Comment: I intended full ionization.  Can a hydrogen still be liquefied if all of it's electrons are stripped off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liquid hydrogen bubble chambers show that LH2 can be ionized.  The LH2 is supercooled. A traveling particle ionizes sone atoms, which then nucleate the formation of bubbles as the LH2 boils.